# Render mesh 3D vertices in Three.js (faces)

Tags: javascript, three.js, autocad, vertices

Given 200+ vertices generated by the AutoCad API in the form of an array of vectors {X:,Y:,Z:}, I am trying to render them in THREE.js with no luck.

For now I am making all the possible permutations for the number 200 and connecting all the vertices together - **which I don't think is the way this is done as it gives over 200k faces.**

**EDIT:** My AutoCAD code is getting all the vertices and then it tries to get it's connected vertices' ids (vertex1 and vertex2). GetHashCode() doesn't work though. The problem isn't that it returns huge id numbers like 148335760 and 682610240. The problem is that these ids are not unique and they happen to be defined and they are not connected to any other vertices.

AutoCAD code:

```
//data structures for serialisation
public class EdgeMe
{
    public int vertex1;
    public int vertex2;
}
public class VertexMe
{
    public int id;
    public Point3d Point;
    public List<EdgeMe> Edges = new List<EdgeMe>();
}

public class DataMe{
    public Extents3d extents;
    public string layer;
    public List<VertexMe> points = new List<VertexMe>();
}


//...


// Get each Solid3d in modelspace and add its extents
// to the list
foreach (var id in ms)
{
    var obj = tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
    var sol = obj as Solid3d;

    DataMe dataMe = new DataMe();
    if (sol != null)
    {
        dataMe.extents = sol.GeometricExtents;
        dataMe.layer = sol.Layer;
        using (var brep = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.BoundaryRepresentation.Brep(sol))
        {
            foreach (var vertex in brep.Vertices)
            {
                VertexMe vertexMe = new VertexMe();
                vertexMe.Point = vertex.Point;
                vertexMe.id = vertex.Brep.GetHashCode();
                foreach(var edge in vertex.Edges)
                {
                    EdgeMe edgeMe = new EdgeMe();
                    edgeMe.vertex1 = edge.Vertex1.Brep.GetHashCode();
                    edgeMe.vertex2 = edge.Vertex2.Brep.GetHashCode();
                    vertexMe.Edges.Add(edgeMe);
                }

                dataMe.points.Add(vertexMe);
            }
        }
    }
    sols.Add(dataMe);
}
```

Javascript code:

```
var faces = function(vertices) {
    var results = [];

    var vertex = [0, 1, 2];
    results.push(vertex.slice());

    while(true) {
        vertex[2]++;
        if(vertex[2] > vertices) {

            vertex[1]++;
            if(vertex[1] >= vertices) {
                vertex[0]++;
                vertex[1] = vertex[0] + 1;

                if(vertex[0] > vertices - 2)
                    return results;
            }

            vertex[2] = vertex[1] + 1;
        }

        results.push(vertex.slice());
    }

};

var generate = function( ... ) {
    // Process each box, adding it to the scene
    for (var sol in sols) { 
        var s = sols[sol];
        var vertices = [];

        for(var vertix in s.points) {// deserialize
            vertix = s.points[vertix];

            vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(vertix.X, vertix.Y, vertix.Z));
        }

        var holes = [];
        var triangles, mesh;
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices = vertices;
        var xfaces = faces(vertices.length);

        for(var i = 0; i < xfaces.length; i++) {
            geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( xfaces[i][0], xfaces[i][1], xfaces[i][2] ));
        }
        geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        geometry.computeVertexNormals();

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, customimg );

        mesh.rotation.set( Math.PI/2, 0, 0);

        root.add(mesh);
    }
}
```

Regards,

Ioan

Comment: @gaitat you are right. please make it a post to make it the answer.

Comment: show AutoCAD code and maybe I'll be able to help you

Comment: Hi @DmitriyZapevalov, have a look at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you are doing. You are trying to guess the connectivity info. That should not be guess work. The application needs to return the connectivity info to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would suggest you use [Forge Model Derivative API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/) to extract the viewable from your file. Once you have the file translated, you can view it using the [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/) (which is based on Three.js, but optimized for engineering files). You'll find several examples at [this Github](http://github.com/Developer-Autodesk).